# Errors while statically compiling poco with ssl in gcc

Tags: linux, gcc, static-libraries, poco-libraries

I have all the .a files in usr/local/lib. Moreover I've deleted all the .so libraries from the folder to ensure that it compiles statically. I'm using this command to compile it-

```
g++ HttpAPICall.cpp  ... main.cpp -Bstatic -L/usr/local/lib/ -lPocoUtil -lPocoXML -lcrypto -lssl \
-lPocoCrypto -lgumbo -lPocoNet -lPocoJSON -lPocoNetSSL -lPocoFoundation -luuid -std=gnu++11 -o analyzer
```

I'm getting the following error-

```
/usr/local/lib//libPocoNetSSL.a(SSLManager.o): In function `Poco::Net::SSLManager::appConfig()':
SSLManager.cpp:(.text+0x383): undefined reference to `Poco::Util::Application::_pInstance'
SSLManager.cpp:(.text+0x3b5): undefined reference to `Poco::Util::Application::_pInstance'
/usr/local/lib//libPocoNetSSL.a(SSLManager.o): In function `Poco::Net::SSLManager::initPassphraseHandler(bool)':
SSLManager.cpp:(.text+0xd58): undefined reference to `Poco::Util::AbstractConfiguration::getString(std::string const&, std::string const&) const'
SSLManager.cpp:(.text+0xdd6): undefined reference to `Poco::Util::UnknownOptionException::UnknownOptionException(std::string const&, int)'
SSLManager.cpp:(.text+0xe01): undefined reference to `Poco::Util::UnknownOptionException::~UnknownOptionException()'
SSLManager.cpp:(.text+0xe06): undefined reference to `typeinfo for Poco::Util::UnknownOptionException'
/usr/local/lib//libPocoNetSSL.a(SSLManager.o): In function `Poco::Net::SSLManager::initCertificateHandler(bool)':
SSLManager.cpp:(.text+0x15a8): undefined reference to `Poco::Util::AbstractConfiguration::getString(std::string const&, std::string const&) const'
```

I've read that the order or compilation matters in such case. I've tried -WL,--start-group --end-group as well. No luck with that. The same code using mac static libraries is getting compiled easily on xcode. Also, by using the dynamic libraries, the code compiles fine on linux as well. Kindly help me with static compiling on linux.

Comment: There are no OpenSSL related linker errors. The linker is single pass, so it does *not* revisit past libraries. That means `-lPocoUtil` must follow `-lPocoNetSSL` because `PocoNetSSL` uses symbols from `PocoUtil`. The easiest way to fix it when you don't know the library dependencies is to take your libraries and list them twice. I.e., `-la -lb -lc -ld -la -lb -lc -ld`. If a symbol is unsatisfied after visiting the first four libraries, it will be satisfied when visiting them again. In your case, you might try `<POCO libraries listed twice> -lgumbo -lssl -lcrypto -luuid`.